# Change The Border For a Table in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

what I want to do is to change the border for a table (#mytable) by a J.S function depends on the value that the user enters (ex: user entered 3 => border="3")

I am using the following code which is existed in an external file called size.js

```
function chooseBorder (size){
    switch (size) {
        case "3":
        document.getElementById("mytable").style.border = "3";
        break;
        case "5":
        document.getElementById("mytable").style.border = "5";
        break;
        case "7":
        document.getElementById("mytable").style.border = "7";
        break;
        case "9":
        document.getElementById("mytable").style.border = "9";
        break;
        default:
        //make border = 0 
        document.getElementById("mytable").style.border = "0";
        break;
    }
}
```

Then in the HTML I wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title> select a border size </title>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "size.js" > </script>
        <script>
            number = window.prompt("Please select a size for table border\n 3(3 pixel border)\n 5(5 pixel border)\n 7(7 pixel border)\n 9(9 pixel border)");
        </script>



    </head>
    <body onload="chooseBorder(number)">
        <table id="mytable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan = "4">Northern New Jersey Profit</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th></th>
               <th>April</th>
               <th>May</th>
               <th>June</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <th>Montclair</th>
               <td>100</td>
               <td>80</td>
               <td>90</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th>Clifton</th>
               <td>79</td>
               <td>80</td>
               <td>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th>Newark</th>
               <td>100</td>
               <td>95</td>
               <td>91</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Problem is nothing changes on loading the page, something wrong in my code. Thanks :)

Comment: F12 and debug is your friend.

Comment: yeah I know that, I am using Firebug it seems that everything is good except changing the css as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a minor change but a big impact:
instead of

`document.getElementById("mytable").style.border = "3";`
use

`document.getElementById("mytable").border= 3;`

so your function becomes this:

```
function chooseBorder (size){
    switch (size) {
        case "3":
        document.getElementById("mytable").border= "3";
        break;
        case "5":
        document.getElementById("mytable").border = "5";
        break;
        case "7":
        document.getElementById("mytable").border = "7";
        break;
        case "9":
        document.getElementById("mytable").border = "9";
        break;
        default:
        //make border = 0 
        document.getElementById("mytable").border = "0";
        break;
    }
}
```

and you're good to go

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use the `borderWidth` property?

Comment: I tried that before but it set ONLY the outside borders not on each raw and column

Comment: if you want to set the border for a table in html you use border="3" and it applies the borders on every raw and column that's why I am using
document.getElementById("mytable").style.border = "3"

Comment: this will give you inner grid borders too

Comment: Exactly what I want an inner grid :)

Comment: Happy to help - it's always easier for a fresh set of eyes ;)